# pic is not displaying in infoBox in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I am not able to find the error why the pic is not getting displayed inside the infoBox, shinyApp.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
a <- 45

ui <-   shinyUI(
dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "ABC"),
dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody(
  fluidPage(
    infoBox("BCD", a, div(img(src = "img.png", width = 100), style = "text- 
align: center;"))
  )
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

1. Save the above script as `app.R`
2. In the folder of `app.R`, create a folder named `www` and save `img.png` in it
3. hit the **Run App** button on RStudio (top right)

Comment: Thank you. Now I got the exact problem where it was stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the addResourcePath function for a more flexibel solution:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/addResourcePath.html